# Passing objects to functions in php

Tags: php, oop

I have a static function in an object that does some stuff and returns an object like so:

```
$objectA = ObjectA::getItem();
```

Then I have a function that makes other types of objects and returns an array of them, part of these types of objects require the `$objectA`, so it gets passed in like so:

```
$arrayOfObjectB = ObjectB::getStuff($objectA);
```

When constructing the `$arrayOfObjectB` I change a part of `$objectA` which will be a part of `$objectB`.

Something like this:

```
public static function getStuff($objectA)
{
    $arrayOfObjectB = array();
    foreach(...loops through some stuff)
      {

           $objectA->setSomething($variableChangedDuringLoop);
           $objectB = new ObjectB($objectA);
           $arrayOfObjectB[] = $objectB;
      }
}
```

what happens is that all of the `$objectA->something` in `$arrayOfObjectB` will have set to the same thing as the last item in the loop, what I would like to happen is for the `$something` to hold separate values set during the loop.

I could clone the objects each time during the loop and then set them, that would work.
But this approach seems 'wrong'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a reference to `$objectA` to a function or a constructor, no copies of the object are made. If you make modifications to `$objectA`, you're affecting the same instance of the object as existed outside the the function (or constructor). If you want independent instances, you'll need to make a copy of the object. Something like this:

```
public static function getStuff($objectA)
{
    $arrayOfObjectB = array();
    foreach(...loops through some stuff)
      {
           // make a copy of $objectA
           $objectAClone = new ObjectA();
           $objectAClone->setX($objectA->getX());
           $objectAClone->setY($objectA->getY());
           ...
           $objectAClone->setSomething($variableChangedDuringLoop);
           $objectB = new ObjectB($objectAClone);
           $arrayOfObjectB[] = $objectB;
      }
}
```

Comment: I am already doing that, as i have mentioned at the end of the question, probably should have mentioned that way earlier, sorry about that. My question is basically, is there a better way of doing this than cloning objects?

Comment: Nope. That's the way. Make a clone. It's not wrong. If you need a whole array filled with objects with different states, they can't all be the same instance. You'll need n independent instances for an array of size n. No way around that. If you want the code to look a little cleaner, you can extract the cloning operation into a separate method.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you need to clone your object. If it feels wrong it's probably because what you're trying to do is not really correct.

I could propose a better solution, but I need to know what you're actually doing with these values.